# Batched tensor multiplication with numpy

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I am trying to perform the following matrix and tensor multiplication, but batched.

[image: matrix and tensor multiplication]

I have a list of `x` vectors:

```
x = np.array([[2.0, 2.0], [3.0, 3.0], [4.0, 4.0], [5.0, 5.0]])
```

and the following matrix and tensor:

```
R = np.array(
    [
        [1.0, 1.0],
        [0.0, 1.0],
    ]
)
T = np.array(
    [
        [
            [2.0, 0.0],
            [0.0, 0.0],
        ],
        [
            [0.0, 0.0],
            [0.0, 2.0],
        ]
    ]
)
```

The batched matrix multiplication is relatively straightforward:

```
x.dot(R.T)
```

However I am struggling with the second part.

I tried using `tensordot` but with no success so far. What am I missing?

Comment: To use `dot` or `@` focus on the `last of 1st and second to the last of 2nd` rule.  You may need to add dimensions to `x` to achieve that.

Comment: What are the shapes of `T` and `x` in actual use-case?

Comment: @hpaulj looks like the answer from Han is going in that direction, but this is completely new to me.

Comment: @Divakar T would be 4x4 or 6x6 and x would be 1e6 x 6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since cache usage isn't an issue on a sequence of small tensors (as it would be for general dot products of large matrices) it is easy to formulate the problem with simple loops.

**Example**

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
import time

@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True)
def tensor_mult(T,x):
  res=np.empty((x.shape[0],T.shape[0]),dtype=T.dtype)
  for l in nb.prange(x.shape[0]):
    for i in range(T.shape[0]):
      sum=0.
      for j in range(T.shape[1]):
        for k in range(T.shape[2]):
          sum+=T[i,j,k]*x[l,j]*x[l,k]
      res[l,i]=sum
  return res
```

**Benchmarking**

```
x = np.random.rand(1000000,6)
T = np.random.rand(6,6,6)

#first call has a compilation overhead (about 0.6s)
res=tensor_mult(T,x)

t1=time.time()
for i in range(10):
  #@divakar
  #Tx = np.tensordot(T,x,axes=((1),(1)))
  #out = np.einsum('ikl,lk->li',Tx,x)

  res=tensor_mult(T,x)

print(time.time()-t1)
```

**Results (4C/8T)**

```
Divakars solution: 191ms
Simple loops: 62.4ms
```

Comment: I have a numba error happening there `  for l in nb.prange(x.shape[0]):` : what version of Python and Numba are you using ?

Comment: Python 3.6.3, Numba 0.39dev

Comment: I am with "Python 3.6.3 :: Intel Corporation" and "numba 0.38.0".

Comment: Which error is it exactly? Does it work without prange?

Comment: I doesn't compile apparently. ImportError: dlopen(/Users/chernals/miniconda3/envs/ipy3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/npyufunc/workqueue.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: __ZN3tbb19task_scheduler_init27internal_blocking_terminateEb
  Referenced from: /Users/chernals/miniconda3/envs/ipy3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/npyufunc/workqueue.cpython-36m-darwin.so
  Expected in: /usr/local/Cellar/root/HEAD-13abf81_1/lib/root/libtbb.dylib
 in /Users/chernals/miniconda3/envs/ipy3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numba/npyufunc/workqueue.cpython-36m-darwin.so

Comment: I never had errors like that. Looks like a problem with your Python or Numba installation. Maybe a reinstall would help...

Comment: it works just fine now, don't know what happened at the time.

Answer (score 2):

We can use a combination of `tensor matrix-multiplication` with [`np.tensordot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc//numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) and [`einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) to basically do it in two steps -

```
Tx = np.tensordot(T,x,axes=((1),(1)))
out = np.einsum('ikl,lk->li',Tx,x)
```

#### Benchmarking

Setup based on OP's comments :

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: x = np.random.rand(1000000,6)

In [3]: T = np.random.rand(6,6,6)
```

Timings -

```
# @Han Altae-Tran's soln
In [4]: %%timeit
   ...: W = np.matmul(T,x.T) 
   ...: ZT = np.sum(W*x.T[np.newaxis,:,:], axis=1).T
   ...: 
1 loops, best of 3: 496 ms per loop

# @Paul Panzer's soln-1
In [5]: %timeit np.einsum('ijk,lj,lk->li', T, x, x)
1 loops, best of 3: 831 ms per loop

# @Paul Panzer's soln-2
In [6]: %timeit ((x[:, None, None, :]@T).squeeze()@x[..., None]).squeeze()
1 loops, best of 3: 1.39 s per loop

# @Paul Panzer's soln-3
In [7]: %timeit np.einsum('ijl,lj->li', T@x.T, x)
1 loops, best of 3: 358 ms per loop

# From this post's soln
In [8]: %%timeit
   ...: Tx = np.tensordot(T,x,axes=((1),(1)))
   ...: out = np.einsum('ikl,lk->li',Tx,x)
   ...: 
1 loops, best of 3: 168 ms per loop
```

Comment: Always forget about tensordot.

Comment: @Divakar : could you let me know about some details for the timing: CPU, Python version, etc? Thanks!

Comment: One important thing to keep in mind when using `np.einsum` is that its `optimize` flag is `False` by default. For tensors of large rank and/or dimensionality it can often be substantially faster to set `optimize='greedy'` or `optimize='optimal'`.

Also, `np.einsum_path` can be used to pre-compute a path for use in repeated calls with the same subscripts to limit the optimization overhead.

Sometimes optimizing isn't worth it though, so be sure to test it for your subscripts/dimensionality.

Answer (score 1):

You can more or less directly translate your formula to an `einsum`:

```
>>> np.einsum('ijk,lj,lk->li', T, x, x)
array([[ 8.,  8.],
       [18., 18.],
       [32., 32.],
       [50., 50.]])
```

Only using `@`:

```
>>> ((x[:, None, None, :]@T).squeeze()@x[..., None]).squeeze()
array([[ 8.,  8.],
       [18., 18.],
       [32., 32.],
       [50., 50.]])
```

Or a hybrid:

```
>>> np.einsum('ijl,lj->li', T@x.T, x)
array([[ 8.,  8.],
       [18., 18.],
       [32., 32.],
       [50., 50.]])
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm indeed not familiar enough with `einsum`. I'm concerned about the performance of `einsum` compared to `dot`; in my case I'm using the Intel distribution for Python and the speed gain on `dot` is significant. Do you think there would be a way to use `dot` so that the same optimizations can take place ?

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by Paul, einsum is an easy way to accomplish the task, but if speed is a concern, then it's generally better to stick to typical numpy functions.

This can be accomplished by writing out the equation and translating the steps into matrix operations.

Let `X` be the `m x d` matrix of data you want to batch over, and `Z` be the `m x d` result you desire. We will arrive at `Z.T` (transpose) because it's easier.

Notice that in order to arrive  at the equation for the `R` contribution we can write

[image]

Then we can this as a numpy matrix multiply `R.dot(X.T)`.

Similarly, observe that the `T` contribution is

[image]

Inside the parenthesis is a batch matrix multiply between `T` and `X.T`. Thus, if we define the quantity inside the parenthesis to be

[image]

We can arrive at it in numpy using `W = np.matmul(T,X.T)`. Continuing our simplification, we see that the `T` contribution is

[image]

Which is equivalent to `np.sum(W*X.T[np.newaxis,:,:], axis=1)`. Putting everything together, we end up with

```
W = np.matmul(T,X.T) 
ZT = R.dot(X.T) + np.sum(W*X.T[np.newaxis,:,:], axis=1) 
Z = ZT.T
```

For larger batch sizes, this is about 3-4 times faster than the einsum function when `d=2`. If we were to avoid using as many transposes, it could perhaps be even a bit faster.

Comment: Thanks for the great step by step explanation. Also, so far, your last method is the fastest!