# Vectorized multiplication of several sequences of 2x2 matrices

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

For the unvectorized version, I have a sequence of `(2, 2)` shaped matrices (i.e. a ndarray of shape `(n, 2, 2)`) and need to multiply them (matrix multiplication) sequentially, meaning `n` sequential matrix multiplications. 
This is what a minimal example would look like

```
def get_matrix_product_eig_val(J):
    # J holds the sequence of matrices to multiply and has shape=(n, 2, 2)
    M = np.identity(2, dtype=np.double)
    for i in range(n_gens):
        M = np.matmul(M, J[i])
    eig_val, eig_vec = np.linalg.eig(M)  # eig_val is what I'm interested in
    return eig_val
```

Now I have an array of `k` such sequences of matrices (a ndarray of shape `(k, n, 2, 2)`) and need to do the same sequential matrix product for each of the `k` entries.
The naive approach would be to do

```
# Now J has shape=(k, n, 2, 2)
for i in range(k):
    eig_vals[i] = get_matrix_product_eig_val(J[i, :, :, :])
```

Is there a way to get rid of the loop and do this in a vectorized way?

Notes:

1) `n` is expected to be in the order of magnitude of ~100. `k` can be anywhere between ~100 to ~10,000

2) Some people have suggested replacing the inner loop with `np.linalg.multi_dot`. This actually slows things down considerably

3) I can see a distant future application for `3x3` matrices, but a specific solution for `2x2` is fine. Either way all matrices will be square, and will have the same dimensions

Comment: Are you looking for `np.linalg.multi_dot`?

Comment: `multi_dot` does the multiplication sequentially.  All it adds is a test to see if there's any advantage doing the multiplications in a different order.  If all arrays have the same shape, there's no advantage to using it.

Comment: Can you cast the problem as one of doing a `n` sequential multiplication of (k,l,2,2) arrays?  `matmul` can multiply one `(k,l,2,2)` array with another.  `A1 @ A2 @ A3 ...`

Comment: If your goal is performance, you can do this quite like that https://stackoverflow.com/a/51062850/4045774 If the small matrices are always 2x2 in dimension there may be further improvement possible. Just update your question with a realistic full working example...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in range(n - 1):
    J[:, i + 1, :, 0] = np.broadcast_to((J[:, i+1, 0, 0])[..., None], (k, 2)) * J[:, i, :, 0] + \
                        np.broadcast_to((J[:, i+1, 1, 0])[..., None], (k, 2)) * J[:, i, :, 1]
    J[:, i + 1, :, 1] = np.broadcast_to((J[:, i+1, 0, 1])[..., None], (k, 2)) * J[:, i, :, 0] + \
                        np.broadcast_to((J[:, i+1, 1, 1])[..., None], (k, 2)) * J[:, i, :, 1]

eig_vals, _ = np.linalg.eig(J[:, -1, :, :])
```